# SQL Server 2008 Managment Objects: posso desinstalar?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Por favor, é uma dúvida simples. Estou começando a estudar SQL e baixei a versão 2012 Express. Com ela veio o SQL Server 2008 Managment Objects. Posso desinstalar sem qualquer preocupação ou ele é importante para o funcionamento do 2012?

Desde já agradeço.

Vitor.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Vitor podes desinstalar sem qualquer problema, não vai ter impacto no engine do SQL.

Como se refere na Microsoft [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557(v=sql.105).aspx)

SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) are objects designed for programmatic management of Microsoft SQL Server. You can use SMO to build customized SQL Server management applications. Although SQL Server Management Studio is a powerful and extensive application for managing SQL Server, there might be times when you would be better served by an SMO application.
For example, the user applications that control the SQL Server management tasks might have to be simplified to meet the needs of new users and to reduce training costs. You might have to create customized SQL Server databases, or create an application for creating and monitoring the efficiency of indexes. An SMO application might also be used to include third-party hardware or software seamlessly into the database management application.

Resumindo são objectos que te facultam meios para desenvolvimento de aplicações para gerir o SQL Server EX:. tal como se fosses construir o teu próprio SQL Server Management Studio. Espero ter-te ajudado